# How do you read from a connection without creating a temp byte slice in Go

Tags: go

The data being sent to my `net.Conn` are packets using TCP network. These packets are all different sizes. How would I make a buffer that's the exact size of the data coming in?
Currently I'm allocating a byte slice which has the biggest packet possible and then slicing it again.

```
for{
    data := make([]byte, 2097151)
    r, _ := (*c).Read(data)
    data = data[:r]
}
```

Comment: Read returns whatever data is available, not a full “packet”.  You need to add some sort of message framing.  If that framing is a length prefix, that length will tell you the number of bytes to allocate.

Comment: Probably a packet tells you how long it is... but you haven't given us those details :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bufio` to read from client

A basic example

```
func TCPServerReadFromConnection() {
    server, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer server.Close()

    conn, err := server.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    // This is a scanner for accepting the data coming over connection
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        val := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed, but I noticed when printing the bytes both packets are in it. How can I avoid that

Comment: What do you mean by both packets?

Comment: I wrote to the server 2 different byte slices and the scanner returned it as one byte slice

Comment: `Scanner.Scan()` [scans a buffer](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) until it hits a `newline` or `\n`.

Comment: I changed the Split function and that seems to work, I get the same response back but the second time I get the two different byte slices for each packet

Comment: What is your expected input and output?

Comment: Ok after removing my go routines I get the data as expected. I'll have to figure out what's causing my go routines to be so slow  that's causing the data to stack up before reading it